# Retina photograph support for responsive websites

Tags: css, responsive-design, image

I've come across a few scripts for serving retina photos to devices with a 2× pixel density:

- [Retina.js](http://retinajs.com) — seems display backgrounds, instead of inline images: looks for `@2x` filenames.
- [Retinise.js](http://dahliacreative.com/retinisejs/) — uses `data-src`, what's that? How is browser support?
- [Automatic Conditional Retina Images](http://shauninman.com/tmp/retina/) — uses .htaccess `mod_rewrite` and simple JS.

(I'm ignoring CSS background images in this, **only concerned with `img` elements that are photographs** — ignoring graphics as I try to serve those as SVGs.)

I want to make sure that devices that support retina images get the full spiel, and that low-bandwidth (i.e. small screen) ones don't (and so that they don't have to download both).

**Which solution follows best-practice for a mobile-first and semantic approach?**

---

It seems that responsive images still do not have a unanimous best solution (regarding bandwidth, etc.), and coupling this with retina images makes it more complicated...

I'm asking because it seems that the Retinise.js documentation implies that because it uses `data-src`, only the needed images is downloaded — does that mean that since Retina.js uses `src` it downloads both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I authored retinise.js as a lot of retina solutions out there actually serve up both images meaning massive bandwidth usage for the user, by using a custom data attribute you stop the browser downloading the original image.

My plugin does not however take into account the users connection type, e.g. 3g vs. WiFi as there is currently no way of detecting this other than doing a simple speed test, which you could modify my plugin to include.

I've used the project on several sites I've authored now, all with good results :)

As for older browser support, It will work as long as JS is enabled as the data-src is replaced with src attribute.

For support for non JS browsers you can just use a no script tag, as described in the documentation.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your input! Can you comment on how your script stacks up to `Retina.js` and `ACRI`?

Comment: I've only had experience with retina.js as as far as I can tell it still downloads the original image as well as the retina version, where as my plugin only serves the image you need not both, saving bandwidth.

I'm not sure what else retina.js offers but the idea behind my plugin was to make it as small and simple as possible.

If you want a simple plugin to retinise your images then I think it is perfect for just that, if you need more functionality then you are probably best to find something else.

Either way it would be great to get some feedback and know what people think.

Comment: I also plan on extending it to include a speed test to restrict retina images on 3G connections in the near future as well.

It's also important to note that my plugin only retinises inline images, background images as this can all be handled in the css!

Comment: That's awesome Simon. I will give it a try and get back to you! Looking forward to hearing about any updates — will follow [you on Twitter](https://twitter.com/dahliacreative).

Comment: Seems that `Retinise.js` is superior to `Retina.js` — and I don't really see any additional functions that the latter has. Seems to do the same, but a bit worse. Yours also seems to be more (if not completely) cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, If you have any feedback or issues etc, it' now up on git hub :) https://github.com/dahliacreative/retinise.js

Comment: Keep checking back on the plugin, I am making tweaks and ironing it out weekly!

Comment: Nice! Is the latest always the most stable?

Comment: Yep, I'll only update with stuff that works! Another update just now to stop images loading at retina size then jumping down to the correct size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that responsive images don't have a best solution, `max-width:100%` has always worked well enough for me.

`data-` attributes are new to HTML5 and allow you to add any custom data to an element without abusing the `rel` attribute. Bootstrap makes heavy use of `data-` attributes, as does jQuery Mobile.

Yes, I think Retina.js does (or at least used to) serve both sizes of images to devices, but only one is shown. If Retinise overcomes that I would say that was a massive benefit

Comment: Perhaps it was ambiguous, but by "no best solution" I meant exactly with things like these: making mobile devices download large files they'll never need (I will correct my post, thanks). Interesting, so it seems that Retinise.js overcomes serving two images at the cost of using an HTML5 `data-` attribute, which I assume, has no fallback on older browsers?

Comment: Well, on older browsers, the attributes should still appear, and you should still be able to select them from script, the only problem is that if they are used, for example, in a document with an html 4.01 doctype, they will be flagged as invalid. They won't cause any *actual* problems though afaik :)

Comment: So the following will render as an image on IE6? `<img data-src="/img/path/non-retina.jpg" data-alt="My Image" class="retina" />`

Comment: Having not used Retinise before I can't give you a cast-iron guarantee that IE6 will not blow up, but, I can say that the attribute will be present in IE6, as it will be present in any other browser. Whether IE6 can handle retinise (or vice-versa) I wouldn't know without testing...Retinise itself makes no claim of supporting any browsers so I think the only way you will know for sure is to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just started using ZURB Foundation Interchange and I'm really loving it so far.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html

You use a data-interchange attribute with an empty src tag, then interchange writes in the correct src location based built-in or custom @media queries.

Here's an example:

```
<img data-interchange="[/path/to/default.jpg, (default)], [/path/to/bigger-image.jpg, (large)]">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for sharing. As for the question at hand here: Interchange relies on JavaScript to load images, and `<noscript>` for search engines, etc. — so I wouldn't say that this is a semantic approach